# Why this simple Batch method doesn't work as expected?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a simple batch method in `c++`, here is my method:

```
vector<vector<string>> batch(vector<string> source, int count)
{
    vector<string> temp;
    vector<vector<string>> result;
    int counter = 0;
    for (auto x : source) {
        if (counter == count) {
            result.push_back(temp);
            temp.clear();
            counter = 0;
        }
        else {
            temp.push_back(x);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    if (temp.size() > 0)
        result.push_back(temp);

    return result;
}
```

so given this input and the count = 3:

```
a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c
```

it should return:

```
a,a,a
b,b,b
c,c,c
```

But I'm getting:

```
a,a,a
b,b,c
c
```

I thought the issue related to `temp.clear()` and I have tried to copy elements of `temp` into another `vector` and add that to `result` but it didn't change anything. So, where is my mistake?

This is the code for testing:

```
vector<string> v = { "a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c" };

auto result = batch(v, 3);

for (auto x : result) {
    for (auto y : x){
        cout << y << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to push to temp every iteration in the for loop.

```
if (counter == count) {
    result.push_back(temp);
    temp.clear();
    counter = 0;
}
temp.push_back(x);
counter++;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<vector<string>> batch(vector<string> source, int count)
{
    vector<string> temp;
    vector<vector<string>> result;
    int counter = 0;
    for (auto x : source) {
        temp.push_back(x);
        counter++;
        if (counter == count) {
            result.push_back(temp);
            temp.clear();
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    if (temp.size() > 0)
        result.push_back(temp);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what a shame :) I knew my mistake is simple.. but not as simple as that... thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well, to tell you the truth, I was wondering why would a guy with 60k+ reputation be asking this question, and I was seriously afraid I misunderstood something.  Anyway, it is good that you accepted Tony Jiang's answer, thus encouraging the guy with the small reputation.

Comment: I'm new in c++ coming from C# :) that's why I thought I made a simple mistake somewhere but wasn't expecting it to be that simple.it has nothing to do with language.I guess next time I should read the code more carefully...

Answer (score 1):

Another option you might consider:

```
typedef vector< string > svec;
typedef vector< svec >   vecsvec;
vecsvec batch( svec source, int count )
{
    vecsvec ret;
    while( source.size() > 0 )
    {
        ret.push_back( svec( source.begin(), source.begin() + count ) );
        source.erase( source.begin(), source.begin() + (count > source.size() ? source.size() : count) );
    }
    return ret;
}
```